# SQL: Compare two result from two different selects

Tags: sql-server

I need to determine if our consultents are logging their work correctly. For that I have two different sources: one containing incoming calls and one their logs in our customer system.

Calls are linked to phone numbers and logs are linked to customer numbers. For each of the two sources I have a select that gives me the numbers of distinct combinations of weeknumber and (customer/phone)-numbers for each consultant to find total unique "weekcalls" for a full year. But how do I divide the results of unique logs with the unique calls? And for bonus difficulty, no temp tabels (doesn´t work in Excel)

Select #1

```
SELECT 
count(distinct(concat(datepart(ww,call_datetime),phonenumber))) as 
calls,consultant
FROM calltabel
group by consultant
```

Select #2

```
SELECT 
count(distinct(concat(datepart(ww,log_datetime),phonenumber))) as 
logs,consultant
FROM logtabel
group by consultant
```

results

select #1

```
consultant    calls
eric          10
kimmie        20
```

select #2

```
consultant    logs
eric          5
kimmie        20
```

The combined result should be

```
consultat    calls    logs     result
eric         10        5        0.5
kimmie       20       20        1.0
```

Comment: Full outer join..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the queries like this

```
select t1.consultant, calls, logs, logs/calls as result
(SELECT 
count(distinct(concat(datepart(ww,call_datetime),phonenumber))) as 
calls,consultant
FROM calltabel
group by consultant) as t1
inner join
(SELECT 
count(distinct(concat(datepart(ww,log_datetime),phonenumber))) as 
logs,consultant
FROM logtabel
group by consultant) as t2 on t1.consultant=t2.consultant
```

Or you can do this:

```
select t1.consultant, calls, logs, logs/calls as result from
(
SELECT calltabel.consultant,
count(distinct(concat(datepart(ww,call_datetime),phonenumber))) as calls,
count(distinct(concat(datepart(ww,log_datetime),phonenumber))) as logs    
FROM calltabel 
inner join logtabel on logtabel.consultant= calltabel.consultant
group by calltabel.consultant
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can do inner join:

Select callTable.Consultant, callTable.calls, logTable.logs, logTable.logs/callTable.logs as ‘Result’ from (SELECT 
count(distinct(concat(datepart(ww,call_datetime),phonenumber))) as 
calls,consultant
FROM calltable
group by consultant) as callTable, (SELECT 
count(distinct(concat(datepart(ww,log_datetime),phonenumber))) as 
logs,consultant
FROM logtable
group by consultant) as logTable

Where logTable.consultant = callTable.consultant;
```